# Intercept Unauthenticated request with Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, windows-authentication, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application with Windows authentication enabled, and I want to use a basic interceptor to handle unauthenticated requests, but it is totally skipped because the Windows authentication mechanism blocks the request before entering the interceptor.

Do you know if there is a way to bypass this standard behaviour not blocking the request going in the interceptor pipeline?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: One workaround is to disable Windows authentication on IIS, but anonymous authentication. Then you can send 401.2 challenge response from ASP.NET Core side to emulate Windows authentication. But why do you want to handle unauthenticated requests in such a setup? You might find other approaches for those purposes.

Comment: @LexLi the purpose is to bypass Windows Auth for certain dynamic controllers which are out of control because don't reside in the project but comes from an external nuget.

Answer (score -1):

Use a middleware and declare it before the UseAuthorization

```
public class YourMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public YourMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Before");
// Here you can decide if you want the next step of the pipeline or not, usually you want
        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

```
app.UseMiddleware<YourMiddleware>();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Comment: Hello Dario, thanks for the response, i have already tried this solution but it doesn't work. Seems that the WindowsAuthentication feature has still more priority in the Middelware pipeline.

Comment: The challenge response (401.2) was generated by the Windows authentication module which executes long before ASP.NET Core module in IIS processing pipeline, so any attempt to intercept like above is useless.

Comment: You are right. But I haven't ran an app on IIS for the last 5 years so is completely out of my thought process a Windows environment. I made the example running on kestrel and works. But you are correct: Is not a correct solution if kestrel is behind iis.